# Grass v.dist tool error when measuring distances from line segments to lines

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am using QGIS version 3.18.1-Zürich.

I am trying to measure the distance from various lines I created using the intersection tool, but I keep getting this error when using the v.distance tool:

WARNING: The combination of types is not supported by all formats.

WARNING: No attribute table found -> using only category numbers as attributes

Exporting 33990 features...

5..11..17..23..29..35..41..47..53..59..65..71..77..83..89..95..100

v.out.ogr complete. 33990 features (Unknown (any) type) written to  (GPKG format).

C:\Users\Matthew\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="vector_6070f4eda0a0f311" output="C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_WyqhMr/6573a748916e4ed884cb14f26484b549/from_output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite

ERROR 1: Wrong field type for fid

ERROR: Unable to create column

[image: v.distance inputs]

[image: Dialogue box inputs]

[image: v.distance outputs, but no attribute values]

when I run v.clean on the pipe_incre line layer, as shown in picture below,  I get:

ERROR 1: Wrong field type for fid
ERROR: Unable to create column 
C:\Users\Matthew\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="errora163fd5da5aa4b04b4590ec4cb90f3a6" output="C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_WyqhMr\ef8d0e593e064397973c1fb3065e7b93\error.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
WARNING: No attribute table found -> using only category numbers as attributes
Exporting 4918 features...
5..11..17..23..29..35..41..47..53..59..65..71..77..83..89..95..100
WARNING: 4918 features without category were skipped. Features without category are written only when -c flag is given.
WARNING: Output layer is empty, no features written

[image: v.clean dialogue box inputs]

Answer (score 1):

I removed the fid field from the attribute table and it now works.